# Finding axes of steepest and shallowest curvature at turning point of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, curvature

I have a quadratic form, $f(\mathbf{x}) ={1\over 2}\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{bx} + c = 0$. The turning point, where $f'(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} = 0,$ can be found using $\mathbf{x}_{\mathrm{T}} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}b$.

I need to find the axes of greatest and least curvature of this paraboloid at the turning point. Are these just the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$ corresponding with the largest and smallest eigenvalue respectively?

The matrix `A` looks like a Hessian to my untrained eye, based on how it is calculated (as the weighted sum, for each vector in a set of vectors, of the outer product of the vector with itself), which maybe helps with measuring curvature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvectors give only the direction of principal axes (for central conics and quadrics) not the principal curvature directions.  There's a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167839605000737) for finding Gaussian and mean curvatures for implicit surfaces.  The standard results for general quadrics are summarized as follows:

Using matrix representation,

\begin{align}
  0 &= F(x,y,z) \\
  & \equiv \frac{1}{2}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & z & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g & i \\
    h & b & f & j \\
    g & f & c & k \\
    i & j & k & d
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\ y \\ z \\ 1
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  \\
  \nabla F &= 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g & i \\
    h & b & f & j \\
    g & f & c & k
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\ y \\ z \\ 1
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  \\
  K &= -\frac{1}{|\nabla F|^4} \det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g & i \\
    h & b & f & j \\
    g & f & c & k \\
    i & j & k & d
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  \\
  H &=
  \frac{(\nabla F)^T
    \begin{pmatrix}
      a & h & g \\
      h & b & f \\
      g & f & c
    \end{pmatrix}
  (\nabla F)}{2|\nabla F|^3}-
  \frac{a+b+c}{2|\nabla F|} \\
  \\
  \kappa_{\pm} &= H \pm \sqrt{H^2-K}
\end{align}

The principal directions or lines of curvature are not easy to solve, please refer to [this paper](http://nlpr-web.ia.ac.cn/2007papers/gjkw/gk17.pdf) for your further interest.

For standard paraboloids, the lines of curvature are as follows:

- Elliptic paraboloid $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=\dfrac{2z}{c}$

$$\boldsymbol{x}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{a}{c} \sqrt{a^2-b^2} \sinh u \cos v \\
  \frac{b}{c} \sqrt{a^2-b^2} \cosh u \sin v \\
  \frac{a^2-b^2}{4c} (\cosh 2u-\cosh 2v)
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Hyperbolic paraboloid $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=\dfrac{2z}{c}$

$$\boldsymbol{x}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{a}{c} \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sinh u \cosh v \\
  \frac{b}{c} \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cosh u \sinh v \\
  \frac{a^2+b^2}{4c} (\cosh 2u-\cosh 2v)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Analogous to quadratic polynomials:

\begin{align}
  \mathbb{A}^{T} &= \mathbb{A} \\
  f(\boldsymbol{x}) &=
  \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \mathbb{A} \, \boldsymbol{x}+
  \boldsymbol{b}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}+c \\
  &=
  (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{h})^{T} \mathbb{A}
  (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{h})+k \\
   \boldsymbol{h}
  &=
  -\frac{1}{2} \, \mathbb{A}^{-1} \boldsymbol{b} \\
 k &=
  c-\frac{1}{4} \,  \boldsymbol{b}^{T} \mathbb{A}^{-1} \, \boldsymbol{b} \\
  \nabla f(\boldsymbol{x}) &= 2\mathbb{A} \, \boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b} \\
  \nabla^{2} f(\boldsymbol{x}) &= 2\operatorname{tr}(\mathbb{A})
\end{align}

Note that $\boldsymbol{h}$ is the centre of central quadric (or conic) providing $\det \mathbb{A} \ne 0$.

For paraboloids, $$\det \mathbb{A}=0$$

See also [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666925/cartesian-equation-for-the-curvature-of-a-superellipse/3667673#3667673) of mine for using Hessian matrix to find the curvature of superellipse.

Comment: Thank you for going above and beyond with this detailed answer!