# Perfect square in terms of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

If $a,b\in \mathbb R$ are constants, $x \in \mathbb R$ is the unknown variable, then I know how to perform a perfect square: $ax^2+bx=a(x^2+\frac{bx}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2})-\frac{b^2}{4a}=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}$.

Now my question is what if $a,b$ are $n\times n$ constant matrices and $x \in \mathbb R^n$ is a $n\times 1$ unknown vector, $c$ is a constant vector?

How to perform a perfect square for $xAx^{T}+xBc$? Can we get something like $A(x-*)^2 -B*$?

Comment: What do you mean by $xBc$?

Comment: This can be analogous to central conic or quadric, see another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3883969/finding-axes-of-steepest-and-shallowest-curvature-at-turning-point-of-a-quadrati/3884131#3884131) for your further interest or application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, we have
$$
x^TAx  + b^Tx = 
\left(x + \frac 12 A^{-1}b\right)^TA\left(x + \frac 12 A^{-1}b\right) - \frac 14 b^TA^{-1}b.
$$
If $A$ is not a symmetric matrix, note that $x^TAx = x^TSx$, where $S = \frac 12 (A + A^T)$, and apply the above to the expression $x^TSx + b^Tx.$

Comment: For dimensional consistency you'll need to change $\,x^T\!\to x\;$ inside of the parentheses.

Comment: @greg Thanks, fixed it

Comment: @BenGrossmann After a second checking, it seems the LHS is not equal to RHS. On the RHS, I got terms like $b^{T}x+x^{T}b$.

Comment: @Topoguy But $b^Tx = x^Tb$; both are just the dot-product of $b$ and $x$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, you are right.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how we could have seen this a priori? With scalars I can follow an algorithm involving factoring and adding and subtracting things, but here all I can see if that I can verify the RHS equals the LHS.

Comment: @EE18 Consider the expression
$$
\left(x + y\right)^TA\left(x + y\right) = x^TAx + 2y^TAx + y^Ty.
$$
You want to find a $y$ such that the "$x$-terms" of this expression match those of $x^TAx + b^Tx$.

Comment: Thank you! @BenGrossmann