# What shape are unit balls in $\mathbb R^d$ with the $L_p$ metric for $2 < p < \infty$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the below figure drawing some examples of unit balls for various $L_p$ metrics.

For $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ we get squares (hyperoctahedra and hypercubes in higher dimensions, respectively), and when $p=2$ we get a circle (spheres in higher dimensions).

For intermediary values of $p$, how would one describe what shape these balls are?

Would they be considered ellipses?

[image]

Comment: Popular term: superellipse ($d=2$) and superellipsoid ($d > 2$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse . Also "Lamé curve" ($d=2$).

Comment: Ah, thank you @GEdgar - this is exactly what I was looking for and opens the door to learn more about these kinds of shapes.

Comment: That article says the case $d=2, p=4$ is called a "squircle".  But I must admit I have not heard this term elsewhere.

Comment: I noticed that. Apparently squircles generalize to spherical cubes, or "hypersphubes" (at least according to someone!). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle#p-norm_notation

Comment: You might be interested in this [*post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666925/cartesian-equation-for-the-curvature-of-a-superellipse).